# Node won't allow CSS because MIME type text/html is not a supported stylesheet

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to load a stylesheet in a HTML file that is served from Node Express, but I keep getting this error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have looked at similar questions here on SO, but none have solved the problem. I added `type=text/css` to the links and tried all possible kinds of different paths to the css file.

None of these links will load the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/create/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./create/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:3000/create/style.css">
```

Folder structure

```
server.js
    create(folder)
       -index.html
       -style.css
```

server.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)

app.get('/create', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/create/index.html');
})

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000')
});
```

Comment: Here is a thread for serving static files, the guy had the same MIME issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182092/mime-type-error-even-with-express-static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> None of these links will load the CSS file

Yes, the problem is the MIME type associated with the file, changing the link won't change the MIME type. Except if you serve a different route with a different MIME type for the same file (do you ?).

The MIME type of interest here is text/css.

You need to change the header of your HTTP request before sending it.

You can do this [with express by setting the options](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile) when calling sendFile() :

Comment: But `sendFile()` is sending a `index.html` file. Maybe it's not allowed to load CSS files in a HTML file that was sent using `sendFile()`?

Comment: Yes it is allowed, but there is a subtility : once the HTML file is served the browser will parse it and then send another request (for HTTP1.1) to get the CSS file, images, etc. You can view the requests and your server response in the web developper console under a 'network' tab.
This means your server must implement a route to serve the CSS file, like the index.html but with a different MIME type.

Comment: Note that there is a facility in Express to serve static files easily : https://expressjs.com/fr/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks, using the static files option solved the MIME type error! My only problem now is that all static files are served from the same folder. I added two static folders using `app.use(express.static('create'))` and `app.use(express.static('game'))` but the second one is ignored... all styles come from the first folder.

Comment: All the directories and files that you put under the 'static' directory will be served as static. You don't have to create a second static dir, it's similar to Apache's 'public_html' dir.
Imagine your static directory declared in Express is called 'static', you can then access a CSS file in a subdir without declaring it : by example under the route 'public/css/style.css'

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the MIME type error again!  My folder name is now called `static`, and in index.html I just link to './style.css`, but now the CSS can't be found again...

Comment: I guess the CSS link is wrong here, you don't have to put './' before the CSS file name. If your file is under 'static/style.css' then you just write href="style.css" to get it.