# Express error: Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-type, mime

I'm trying to build a simple single page application via express.

Everything works fine until I start creating the classes, then the browser throws the following error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I was hoping that `express.static()` would make that go away but that's not the case.
I'm not very skilled yet with JS, Node and all that, so I apologize for anything dumb here.

My code is quite simple at the moment:

file architecture:

```
-server.js
-[frontend]
+-[static]
++-index.html
++-[js]
+++-index.js
+++-[views]
++++-AbstractView.js
++++-Home.js
-[node_modules]
-package.json
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const App = express()

App.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'static')))
App.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "index.html"))
})
App.listen(3000, () => console.log("server running on port 3000"))
```

index.js:

```
import Home from "./views/Home"

const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null, null, url)
    router()
}

const router = async() => {
    const routes = [{
                path: '/',
                view: new Home()
            },
            // {
            //     path: '/projects',
            //     view: () => console.log('projects')
            // },
            // {
            //     path: '/about',
            //     view: () => console.log('about')
            // },
            // {
            //     path: '/studies',
            //     view: () => console.log('studies')
            // },
        ]
        // test routes for matches
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route => {
        return {
            route: route,
            isMatch: location.pathname === route.path
        }
    })

    /**
     * NEED TO SET 404 PAGE!
     */
    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.isMatch)
    if (!match) {
        match = {
            route: routes[0],
            isMatch: true
        }
    }

    const view = new match.route.view()
    const content = document.querySelector("#app")
    content.innerHTML = await view.getHtml()
    console.log(content);
}

window.addEventListener("popstate", router);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link")) {
            e.preventDefault()
            navigateTo(e.target.href)
        }
    })
    router()
})
```

the Home class (extending and AbstractView general class):

```
import AbstractView from "./AbstractView";

export default class Home extends AbstractView {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.setTitle("Home")
    }
    setTitle(title) {
        document.title = title
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return `<h1>Home</h1>`;
    }
}
```

The generic class:

```
export default class AbstractView {
    constructor() {

    }
    setTitle(title) {
        document.title = title
    }

    async getHtml() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

of course, the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Paolo Iocca</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
        <span class="menu__line"></span>
        <span class="menu__line"></span>
        <span class="menu__line"></span>
    </div>
    <aside class="aside">
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__list__item">
                    <a href="/" class="nav__list__item__link" data-link>home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__list__item">
                    <a href="/projects" class="nav__list__item__link" data-link>projects</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav__list__item">
            <a href="/about" class="nav__list__item__link" data-link>about </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__list__item">
                    <a href="/studies" class="nav__list__item__link" data-link>studies
            </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/static/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope you can help me with this. Thanks a lot.

_____ UPDATE

here's the package.json file, just in case:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    },
    "name": "boilerplate-server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "server.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
        "serve-static": "^1.14.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon server",
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": ""
}
```

Comment: I think there is an import issue somewhere, I would look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182092/mime-type-error-with-express-static-and-css-files) for example.

Comment: If the static middleware does not find the `.js` file for one of the classes, the next middleware would take over and return the `index.html` file instead. That would explain the MIME type error. But your file list contains all needed files. Hm, can you spot a `text/html` response for a `.js` request in your browser's network tab?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen - the network shows all the needed files: a "document"-type localhost and the two scripts index.js and Home.js - all of them with a 200OK status. The thrown error reference points me to the first line of the html file. At least I know that the `express.static()` line is working correctly...

Comment: @YH thanks for pointing me in that direction. I've tested this: created a `/static/css/style.css` with a simple change in the body background color. It works ok so it's definitely not related to the mentioned problem. The scripts reach destination, they just don't apply the due changes and they throw the content-type error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement

```js
import Home from "./views/Home"
```

leads to the request `GET /static/js/views/Home` (*without* `.js` suffix), which the `static` middleware cannot serve. But now the next middleware takes over and responds with the `index.html` file (with `Content-Type: text/html`). That's why you see a 200 OK status, but the browser complains about the wrong content type.

With

```js
express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'static'),
  {extensions: ["js"]});
```

you would instruct the [`static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware to silently add the `.js` suffix.

Comment: that worked, and was also very instructive.  I appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: for the built-in node http module use `request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');`

Comment: Where the reck I'd type this?

Comment: You'd write `app.use(express.static(...))` as part of your server definition.

Answer (score 0):

The error can also be in case you are using TS and importing a package like **leaflet**, without installing the **leaflet types package** (*npm install --save @types/leaflet*) along with it. That happened in my case.