# Using Firebase with npm

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, npm

I would like to use Firebase in my project with NPM and I installed it using "npm i firebase".
This worked fine so I made a new file called "app.js".
Here I would like to put my Firebase code, but it's not working, I get the following error message in my console:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I put the script in my  in HTML with type="module":

```
<script src="./app.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

How can I fix this?
Here's my Firebase code that's in app.js

```
//MODULE DUS GEEN IIFE
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "../../node_modules/firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "../../node_modules/firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "../../node_modules/firebase/database";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();
const database = getDatabase(app);

signin.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("hi")
})
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Pictures of my node modules folder and firebase.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as a normal **text/javascript** instead of **module**

Since modules normally use **strict mode**, it probably doesn't have all the features of a module resulting in the file not loading as expected, as stated here in the **core JS module features**

https://javascript.info/modules-intro#core-module-features

---

Edit: The issue is with the path to the file you're importing. As seen in the screenshot below, this is the directory structure in '**......node_modules/firebase/app**':

[image: node_modules/firebase/app]

So, the file you're importing actually doesn't exist there, that's why the 404 error HTML page.

That method works when running the app in a node environment, like **React**. Now for a browser, there are some files just within the '**......node_modules/firebase/**' directory which can be used in a web-browser environment

For your project, the files are:

```
firebase-app.js
firebase-auth.js
firebase-database.js
```

As in the screenshot below

[image: node_modules/firebase]

So to import them in your file, do it this way:

```
import { initializeApp } from "../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth";
import { getDatabase } from "../../node_modules/firebase/firebase-database";
```

Comment: This won't work since Firebase has to be type="module" and it has imports.

Comment: Oh yeah, try checking this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69677744/express-error-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enforced-for-module-scripts-per-html

Comment: thanks but I am not using Express so can't do any of these things :/

Comment: Check edited answer for the new findings

Comment: I don't think my Firebase is installed this way. I added a screenshot.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess based on your directory structure, you should try and find the correct JS file to link to, (probably under dist) since the path you're importing from won't work when in a web browser environment

Comment: thanks, but there is firebase-app js file anywhere.