# My css is not working in node.js Getting this error (ERROR IN DESCRIPTION) as it is too long

Tags: css, node.js

This is the error I am getting.

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/stylesheets/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This is my index.js file

```
//Requiring Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = require('path');

//To run and parse EJS
const engine = require('ejs-mate');

//Using EJS-Mate
    app.engine('ejs' , engine);
    app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
    app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    //For use of files like js and css in public directory
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))

    app.get('/' , (req , res) => {

    })

    app.get('/home' , (req , res) => {
        res.render('layouts/boilerplate')
    })
```

This is the boilerplate.ejs where i want to add the stylesheet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/">
    <title>BoilerPlate</title>

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
        
    <!-- NAVBAR -->
    <%- include('../partials/navbar.ejs') %>


<!--BOOTSTRAP Javascript-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The bootstrap CSS however is working. So I tried removing the "rel" error goes but the stylesheet is not applied. I also tried to use the base method and still did not work, also added type=text/css, and still didn't work. Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIME type error with express.static and CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182092/mime-type-error-with-express-static-and-css-files)

Comment: _TL;DR_ use `href="/stylesheets/style.css"` (no `/public` prefix)

Comment: Works @Phil , I appreciate it .

Comment: This is what dev tools are for, too: remember to look at your `network` tab, not just the `console` tab, because the network tab would have told you that your CSS file didn't have a 200 status code, but a 404, with the response being an HTML page.